# converting list to an array of fixed size

Tags: java, arrays

Could anyone please explain me why this code snippet works?

```
Object[] op = new Object[0];

ArrayList r = new ArrayList();
r.add("1");
r.add("3");
r.add("5");
r.add("6");
r.add("8");
r.add("10");

op = r.toArray();
System.out.println(op[3]);
```

This prints out 6. I know that you can convert list to array but I was thinking that if the array is fixed size then you can't add further elements. In this case the array op is with fixed size "0" so why/how are the list elements being added to the array? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You need to distinguish between the **reference** to your array object (that is `Object[] op`) and the actual **array object** to which the reference points.

With

```
Object[] op = new Object[0];
```

you are creating an array of size 0 and assign it to the `op` reference.

But then, with

```
op = r.toArray();
```

you are assigning a new array object to the `op` reference. This new array object has been created by the `toArray()` method with the appropriate size.

The earlier array object which was created with `new Object[0];` is now dangling and subject to garbage collection.

Comment: oh yes. I totally forgot that the array variables are also reference variables. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason that this code prints out X instead of ABC:

```
String s = "ABC";
String t = "XYZ";
s = t.substring(0, 1);
System.out.println(s);
```

You're reassigning the value of op, and the new value has nothing to do with the old value.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood one important thing here.
Java identifiers are only pointers to objects, not objects themselves.

Here when you do

```
Object[] op = new Object[0];
```

you create a new instance array with a fixed size of 0, and you point the identifier "op" to it.

But when you later do

```
op = r.toArray();
```

you just overwrite where your former identifier point to. You lose the reference to your first array that will be garbaged collected.
"op" desgin now a new array, your former one just disappear.